# Vagrant Port Forwarding Localhost 8080 and 8000 to Host 8080 and 8000

Tags: ansible, vagrant, port, vagrantfile, forwarding

I am deploying an app on my Centos7 VM using Vagrant and Ansible. I can connect to the app on the VM through localhost:8080 and localhost8000. How can I use port forwarding to access the app on my host machine (Ex. I go to my web browser on my host machine and I can access the app through localhost:8080 and localhost:8000)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
end
```

And for more info refer: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html

After that if you face any issue. Please let me know.

Comment: When I go to localhost:8080 on my host computer, it still does not load :(

Comment: you might have something else running on 8080. you could check the Vagrant startup logs.